# Building Object in Rebol dynamically

Tags: oop, rebol

This works:

```
>> Oblock: [FirstName: ""
[    LastName: ""
[    BirthDate: ""]
== [FirstName: ""
    LastName: ""
    BirthDate: ""
]
>> Person: Make Object! OBlock
>> Person
>> probe Person
make object! [
    FirstName: ""
    LastName: ""
    BirthDate: ""
]
>> Person/FirstName
== ""
>> Person/FirstName: "John"
== "John"
```

But this doesn't work

```
>> List: ["Id" "FirstName" "LastName"]
== ["Id" "FirstName" "LastName"]
>> Person: []
== []
>> foreach attribute List [
[      Append Person to-word rejoin [attribute {: ""}]
[    ]
== [Id: "" FirstName: "" LastName: ""]
>> Person/FirstName
** Script Error: Invalid path value: FirstName
** Where: halt-view
** Near: Person/FirstName
>>
```

Why ?

Answer (score 3):

There are so many ways to do this, but here's one way that adheres closely to the way you seem to envision it:

```
list: [ "Id" "FirstName" "LastName" ]
person: []
forall list [
    repend person [to-set-word first list ""]
]
person: make object! person
print person/FirstName
; == ""
```

In a traditional programming language, you do something like this to set the value of a variable:

```
x = 3;
```

In REBOL, you do this:

```
x: 3
```

In a traditional programming language, `=` is an operator, but `:` is **not** an operator in REBOL. It is a part of the word itself. This is a very important distinction, and it's why what you tried to do above did not work. `x:` is a `set-word!`, and to make one from a string you have to use `to-set-word`.

```
to-set-word "x"
; == x:
```

Also, you seem to be confusing objects and blocks. This is an object:

```
person: make object! [ first-name: "Jasmine" last-name: "Byrne" ]
```

This is a block:

```
person: [ first-name "Jasmine" last-name "Byrne" ]
```

**They are not the same.**

Answer (score 2):

The reboltutorial's "person" block looks like exactly same in appearence with Geogory's.

But in fact person/1(the block) is "id: " in the first post witch type is a string!, id is just only part of it.
in second post, person/1 is "id:",  witch type is set-word!.

This is the essential difference of them.